React Flow - "Handle: No node id", yet I have a node id?
I am integrating a React Flow Canvas inside of a JS environment now, and the error "Handle: No node id" keeps on appearing despite my best attempts at understanding and fixing the source. At the moment I can create nodes and they appear on the canvas, but I cannot drag an edge from a handle, which I assume might be related to this node id error. Each time a new node is added to the canvas, a save is made to Firestore.
Would you have a lead to help me investigate this issue please?
So this is how my code is structured:
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import ZustandProvider from './ZustandProvider.js'
import React from 'react';
import { ReactFlowProvider } from '@xyflow/react';
import Canvas from './Canvas.jsx';

const displayRecord = (recordId) => {
  const root = createRoot(displayContainer);
  root.render(
    <ReactFlowProvider>
      <Canvas recordId={recordId} />
    </ReactFlowProvider>
  );
}

import ReactFlow, { useNodesState, useEdgesState } from 'react-flow-renderer';
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {addEdge, Controls, Background } from '@xyflow/react';
import Type1 from './nodeType1.jsx';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { getFirestore, getDoc, doc, updateDoc, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

const nodeComponents = {
    type1: Type1
  };

const Canvas = ({recordId}) => {
    const [nodes, setNodes, onNodesChange] = useNodesState([]);
    const [edges, setEdges, onEdgesChange] = useEdgesState([]);
    const [recordData, setRecordData] = useState(null);
    const [searchPosition, setSearchPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    const [nodeName, setNodeName] = useState('');
    const [isNodeNamePopupVisible, setIsNodeNamePopupVisible] = useState(false);
    const onConnect = useCallback(
      (params) => setEdges((eds) => addEdge(params, eds)),
      [setEdges]
    );
  
    const handleDoubleClick = (event) => {
      const { clientX, clientY } = event;
      setSearchPosition({ x: clientX, y: clientY });
      setIsNodeNamePopupVisible(true);
    };
    
    const createNode = async (type, label) => {
      const newNodeId = uuidv4();
      const newNode = {
          id: newNodeId,
          type: type,
          position: searchPosition,
          data: { 
            label: label, 
            Component: nodeComponents[type] 
          },
      };

      setNodes((nds) => [...nds, newNode]);
      updateFirestore();
    };
  
    const updateFirestore = async () => {
      const reactFlowData = getReactFlowData();
      try {
          const recordRef = doc(db, 'records', recordId);
          await updateDoc(recordRef, { reactFlow: reactFlowData });
          console.log('Canvas saved successfully.');
      } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error saving canvas:', error);
      }
    };
  
    const getReactFlowData = () => {
      return {
        nodes: nodes.map(node => ({
            id: node.id,
            position: node.position,
            data: node.data,
            type: node.type
        })),
        edges: edges.map(edge => ({
            id: edge.id,
            source: edge.source,
            target: edge.target,
            type: edge.type
        }))
      };
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchRecord = async () => {
          const docRef = doc(db, 'records', recordId);
          const recordSnapshot =  await getDoc(docRef);
  
          if (recordSnapshot.exists()) {
              const data = recordSnapshot.data();
              setRecordData(data);
  
              if (data.reactFlow) {
                  setNodes(data.reactFlow.nodes);
                  setEdges(data.reactFlow.edges);
              }
          } else {
              console.error('Record not found');
          };
      };
      fetchRecord();
    }, [recordId]);
  
    return (
      <div className="record-container">
        <div id="react-flow-canvas">
              <ReactFlow
                nodes={nodes}
                edges={edges}
                nodeTypes={nodeComponents}
                onNodesChange={onNodesChange}
                onEdgesChange={onEdgesChange}
                onConnect={onConnect}
                zoomOnDoubleClick={false}
                fitView
                onDoubleClick={handleDoubleClick}
                onlyRenderVisibleElements={false}
              >
                <Controls className= "react-flow__controls"/>
                <Background />
              </ReactFlow>
              {isNodeNamePopupVisible && (
                <div className="node-name-popup">
                  <form > 
                    <label>
                      Enter a node name:
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        width="100%"
                        value={nodeName}
                        onChange={(e) => setNodeName(e.target.value)}
                        required
                      />
                    </label>
                    <div className="node-type-buttons">
                      <button type="button" onClick={() => createNode('type1', nodeName)}>Type1</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
};

export default Canvas;

The structure I typically defined for my custom nodes is:
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import { Handle, Position } from '@xyflow/react';

function Type1({ id, data, isConnectable }) {
  return (
    <div className="node-type">
        <div className="label">{data.label}</div> 
        <Handle
            id={"a"}
            type="source"
            position={Position.Bottom}
            isConnectable={isConnectable}
        />
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(Type1);

Where ZustandProvider.js is:
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import useStore from './store';

const ZustandProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return <Provider store={useStore}>{children}</Provider>;
};

export default ZustandProvider;

In React Dev Tools I see the HandleComponent under another HandleComponent, under the MaterialNode which itself contains an id.
